# Check if a cell is a substring of a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So, I have a range of cells here (let's call it range A)

[image]

---

And another range (range B)

[image]

---

Please guide me how I can determine each cell of range B is a substring of range A, and display the corresponding range A cell value list, like this?

[image]

Comment: Please provide details on the code you attempted, and explain on the specific issues you encountered. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). Please create MD table with online tool [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables).

Answer (score 1):

```
=TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";", TRUE, IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(A2,B$2:B$4), "")<>"", B$2:B$4, "")), ";")
```

You will need to select a delimiter that suits your data. If you cannot predict  a delimiter that does not appear in the full-string set ("Original List"), this solution will not suit.

This is my layout:

| Original | Check | Match 1 | Match 2 | Match 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | ABCDEFZYZ | =TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";", TRUE, IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(A2,B$2:B$4), "")<>"", B$2:B$4, "")), ";") |  |  |
| XYZ | Test-SKU-1 | =TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";", TRUE, IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(A3,B$2:B$4), "")<>"", B$2:B$4, "")), ";") |  |  |
| SKU | Test-SKU-2 | =TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";", TRUE, IF(IFERROR(SEARCH(A4,B$2:B$4), "")<>"", B$2:B$4, "")), ";") |  |  |

[image: screenshot of excel test file with formulas applied as above]